# How to access div in sharepoint aspx in its webpart codebehind

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

i have an aspx sharepoint page with webpart. how to set display=none to a div in the page(aspx) inside the webpart codebehind(ascx.cs).

code:

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
function ShowGearPage() {
    var gearPage = document.getElementById("GearPage");
    gearPage .style.display = "block";

    var loginPage = document.getElementById("MasterTable");
    loginPage.style.display = "none";
    return true;
}
    </script>


    <div align="center" id="GearPage" style="display:none;">
<div id="s4-simple-card" class="s4-simple-gearpage">
    <div id="s4-simple-card-content">
        <h1>
            <img id="gearsImage" alt="This animation indicates the operation is in progress."
                src="gears_anv4.gif" style="width: 24px; height: 24px; font-size: 0px;"
                align="middle" />
            Processing...
        </h1>
        <div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

ShowGearPage();

I want to hide the GearPage div and show the Master div in the DisplayReportWebPart webpart codebehind.

Answer (score 0):

Add `runat="server"` to the div and use `divId.Attributes("Style","display:none");`

Comment: Just now tried. if i give runat giving error "Code blocks are not allowed in this file." when getting the client id